# Postgres with sinatra results in "database does not exist" on deploy

Tags: ruby, postgresql, deployment, sinatra

While deploying (first deploy) via Capistrano my Sinatra project I've found the problem during first migration (I'm using activerecord):

> FATAL:  database "root@127.0.0.1/app" does not exist

But it connects well on server (ubuntu)

```
root@wallget:~# psql -U root -d app -h 127.0.0.1
psql (8.4.17)
SSL connection (cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.

app=> \q
```

In apps config I have:

```
db = URI.parse(ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || 'postgres:///root@127.0.0.1/app')

  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter  => db.scheme == 'postgres' ? 'postgresql' : db.scheme,
    :host     => db.host,
    :username => db.user,
    :password => db.password,
    :database => db.path[1..-1],
    :encoding => 'utf8'
  )
```

Here is my pg_hba.conf line:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
```

What might be the problem? I'm deploying on my vps, not Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `postgres://root@127.0.0.1/app` (two slashes instead of three)